# Unable to update the left navigation url through powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, navigation

I am trying to update the SharePoint 2013 on premise portal navigation urls though below powershell.
The script is getting executed successfully without any error. But when I am cross checking the site by going to navigation section in site settings.aspx page, no update is there.

Please help me to getting this sorted out.Thanks in advance!

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://demosite.com/sites/apps/stiftelsen"

$FindString="abc"

$linkUrl = $linkUrl.ToLower();

$SPWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch | ForEach-Object {


if($linkUrl.IndexOf($FindString) -gt -1){

    $linkUrl = $_.Url

    Write-Host "Updating $linkUrl with new URL"

    if($_.Title -eq "Application and handling process"){

        $_.Url = $_.Url.Replace($_.Url,"https://google.com")

        $_.Update()

    }

}

}

$SPWeb.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this article to update the link url:
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/find-and-replace-old-link-urls-in-quick.html

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Set Old & New URLs
$OldURL = "http://moss2007.crescent.com"
$NewURL = "http://sharepoint2010.crescent.com"

#Get all sites of the web application
$webs = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All

#Iterate through webs
ForEach ($web in $webs)
{
    #Get the Quick Launch Bar Nodes
    $QuickLaunchNodes = $Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
    #For Top Navigation use: $Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar . TOp Nav may or May not have child nodes

    #Iterate through each Parent nodes of Quick launch
    Foreach ($parentNode in $QuickLaunchNodes)
    {
        If($parentNode.Url -match $OldURL)  #if you want to match Link text, use: $parentNode.Title
        {
            $parentNode.Url = $parentNode.Url.Replace($OldURL,$NewURL)
            $parentNode.Update()
            Write-Host "$OldURL Updated!"
        }
        #Get the Child Nodes
        $childNodes = $parentNode.Children

        #Iterate through child nodes
        Foreach ($childNode in $childNodes)
        {
            If($childNode.Url -match $OldURL)
            {
                $childNode.Url = $childNode.Url.Replace($OldURL,$NewURL)
                $childNode.Update()
                Write-Host "$OldURL Updated!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```